Enclosing ParametricPlot3D to create a solid volume
I'm creating a 3D parametric hourglass shape that I hope to fill, making the center solid to use as a 3D volume, because I can't set parameters to it in COMSOL for simulations right now. I know that a similar question has been asked before, and I tried methods 2 and 3 without much success. I am a bit lost on how method 1 would work here, if at all.
Thank you.
The ParametricPlot:

How it looks between the two balls:

Code:
ClearAll;

t = 0.08;
d = 0.5;
hr2 = Abs[t];

(*Define constants*)
angle = 45 Degree;
ball2x = Cos[angle]*(2*r + d);
ball2h = Sin[angle]*(2*r + d);
r = 1;
diameter = 2*r;
offset = {r, r, r};

(*Initialize centers for spheres*)
basicCenters = {{0, 0, 0}, {ball2x, 0, ball2h}};
centers = # + offset & /@ basicCenters;

(*Define the hourglass shapes*)
widest = 0.6;
hh = 0.5 + d;

createDiscreteHourglass1[center_, direction_, hr2_] := 
  Module[{rotationMatrix, hourglass}, 
   rotationMatrix = 
    RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, Normalize[direction]}];
   hourglass = 
    ParametricPlot3D[
     center + 
      rotationMatrix[{(widest - hr2 + hr2 Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[
          u], (widest - hr2 + hr2 Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[u], 
        hh (v - 0.5)}], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]];
   DiscretizeGraphics[hourglass[[1]]]];

createDiscreteHourglass2[center_, direction_, hr2_] := 
  Module[{rotationMatrix, hourglass}, 
   rotationMatrix = 
    RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, Normalize[direction]}];
   hourglass = 
    ParametricPlot3D[
     center + 
      rotationMatrix[{(widest - hr2 - hr2 Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[
          u], (widest - hr2 - hr2 Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[u], 
        hh (v - 0.5)}], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]];
   DiscretizeGraphics[hourglass[[1]]]];

(*Generate hourglass based on the value of t*)
hourglassCenters = {{ball2x/2, 0, ball2h/2} + offset};
directions = {{ball2x, 0, ball2h}};
discreteHourglasses = 
  If[t < 0, 
   createDiscreteHourglass1[#, #2, hr2] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{hourglassCenters, directions}], 
   createDiscreteHourglass2[#, #2, hr2] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{hourglassCenters, directions}]];

(*Define cuboid boundaries and create region intersections*)
cuboid = Cuboid[{0, 0, r}, {ball2x + diameter, diameter, ball2h + r}];
balls = Ball /@ centers;
intersections = Quiet[RegionIntersection[#, cuboid] & /@ balls];
validIntersections = DeleteCases[intersections, _EmptyRegion];
discreteSpheres = 
  validIntersections /. 
    reg_Ball :> 
     Module[{center, radius}, {center, radius} = List @@ reg;
      DiscretizeRegion[reg]] // Quiet;

(*Combine and export graphics*)
combinedGraphics = 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], discreteSpheres, Blue, 
   discreteHourglasses}, Axes -> True]

(*Export the combined graphics to DXF format*)
Export["half_sphere_hourglass_capillary_bridge.dxf",combinedGraphics, "DXF"]


Do you only want the bule revolution solid which two pieces of the boundary is just  the pieces of the two spheres?

@cvgmt Either works -- Whichever is more convenient. The boundary could either simply be two circular caps that close off either end of the 3D parametric shape, or it could be bounded by the two spheres.

We can relatively easy to construct revolution solid and calculus it volume, but not easy cut such solid by the two balls.
